# Express wildcard rule

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing, single-page-application

I am hosting a single page app with Node and Express. I use the static middleware for the client. I am using path URLs to navigate the app, for example domain.com/profile/134. I am using history.pushState to change pages internally on the client, and this works fine. What I am missing is a wildcard rule on the server to catch all possible paths when the user accesses my page directly to a path that is not root. If I try to access domain.com/profile/134 directly I get this: "Cannot GET /profile/134". I have tried to insert a wildcard get at the end of server.js, but it seems to be hit every time, also when I access the page root. This is my relevant code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../client'));
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    console.log('wildcard');
});
```

Is this the correct GET wildcard rule to achieve what I need, and how can I serve the static client inside this handler? My client side will find the right page afterwards as long as the initial path is preserved. I basically want this wildcard rule to behave the same as the static rule, but keep the initial path.

Comment: can you please post one of routes which you have used before the wildcard ?

Comment: It's this line in the code block: 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../client'));
This serves the static client when accessing the domain root directly. But does not cover all possible paths. I have edited the post to be more clear how my server.js looks like.

Comment: try app.get('/(.*)', function (...) {...}).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hack

```
app.get('/:url', function(req, res) {
  console.log('wildcard');
});
```

or try this one

```
app.get('/(.*)', function(req, res) {
  console.log('wildcard');
});
```

**[edited]: this should work as you expect**:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get(/(.*)/, function(req, res) {
  console.log("req.path", req.path);
  res.send('success');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: app.get('/:url', function(req, res) {
      console.log('wildcard');
    });

This one catches all paths, but if I enter domain.com/settings the path disappears on page load. Only domain.com is left. I need the path to be preserved to open the correct page on the client.

    app.get('/(.*)', function(req, res) {
      console.log('wildcard');
    });

This one doesn't catch any paths, if I try to access domain.com/settings i get the same message in the browser saying "Cannot GET /settings"

Comment: req.params.url - holds path. but this won't work for complex queries like /users/1

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using an npm module named express-history-fallback-api to solve this. Out of the box it solved both simple and advanced paths, like domain.com/settings and domain.com/profile/username

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-history-api-fallback